# AS3 program started messing up after using this.addChild

Tags: actionscript-3, this, parent-child, removechild, addchild

Example Question:

I've recently added a button to my program; When the button is
 clicked, the background music is muted, and the mute button's movieclip is changed into a different one. When clicked again, the
 music unmutes and the movieclip changes again to what it was at first.
 I do this by using the following code:

> ```
> //loading the music:
> var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("teardrop.mp3");
> var s:Sound = new Sound(req);
> var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
> var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
> sTransform.volume = 1;
> myChannel = s.play(0,9999);
>
> //Creating the movieclip and making it a button:
> var sb1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
> sb1.addChild(onS);
> sb1.buttonMode = true;
> sb1.useHandCursor = true;
> sb1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,muter);
>
> //If the Music is muted, unmute it and switch to onS, if not, mute it and switch to offS.
> function muter(e:MouseEvent):void
> {
>   if (sTransform.volume == 1)
>   {
>       sTransform.volume = 0;
>       sb1.removeChild(onS);
>       sb1.addChild(offS);
>   }
>   else if (sTransform.volume == 0)
>   {
>       sTransform.volume = 1;
>       sb1.removeChild(offS);
>       sb1.addChild(onS);
>   }
>   myChannel.soundTransform = sTransform;
> }
> //Note: onS and offS are movieclips which are put into the first scene Since the mute/unmute button is supposed to appear in all of the
> ```

~10 scenes, after using `gotoAndStop(frame, "Scene")` to go from one
 scene to another, I use `this.addChild(sb1)` in each scene to add the
 mute button to that scene.

But for some reason, ever since I did that, my program has been
 messing up. Muting/Unmuting works fine, but in the rest of the
 program: Variables, Buttons, and Textfields either aren't loaded
 properly, or aren't loaded soon enough, because I'm getting the error:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference After a while of travelling from scene to scene,
> ```

which pointed to this line...

> ```
> getCards.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getCardsMenu);
> ```

And recently, this:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. Which was pointing at this line...
>
> var aroz:Array = new Array[nextPart,prevPart];
> ```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Never ever switch scenes without clearing any movieclips already loaded to that scene. Before using `gotoAndStop(frame, "scene")`, Always remove the child that you've been adding to each scene. for example:

```
//some code
function menuScene (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Never forget this line before moving scenes
    this.removeChild(sb1);
    gotoAndStop(1, "Menu Scene");
}
//more code
```

I've posted this so no one ever makes the same mistake I've been making, a mistake that's driven me crazy and made me hate children.

PS: Not real children, I mean the display method xD

Comment: Good advice for beginners, for more experienced coders the real advice is: never, ever use scenes.

Comment: Actually, scenes are the first option when making a program that is, in its entirety, just menus and simple functions. Unless, there's a better way?

Comment: Keep using scenes then no one is stopping you.

Comment: @BotMaster Eh, sorry if that last comment seemed jerkish, it's just the only way I know so far xD  Is there a better way than scenes? I really would like to know :)

Comment: Code only, all assets in library exported to as3 or better yet all assets are loaded externally at runtime.